# Did a crtitical update now getting errors

Tags: updates

My customer clicked the update button and updated number 2.6.2791

now we are getting errors trying to save new images to the site.

Internal Server Error

Could not resolve the subpath “project-images/{slug}”.

I wonder if this is a permissions thing?

regards

Hugh

Comment: What version is the site running now? What does the web server error log mention? Did you upgrade from ``2.6.2791``?  ``2.6.2903`` is the the latest version.  Could be permissions but you'd need to check your web server's error log to find out what's causing the error. Craft shouldn't touch your images folder permissions during an update...

Comment: Craft CMS 2.6.2804 is what is running.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you've got an Assets field inside of a Matrix field somewhere on your site and you're referencing `project-images/{slug}` in that field's upload location setting when it should be `project-images/{owner.slug}`.

At some point, those settings were more loosely enforce, but now the error you're getting will be shown if it is incorrect.

See here for more info: https://craftcms.com/docs/assets-fields#dynamic-subfolder-paths